# Unable to create App Engine App from Terraform: The caller does not have permission, forbidden

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have the following Terraform:

```
data "google_client_config" "current" {
}

resource "google_app_engine_application" "app" {
  project     = data.google_client_config.current.project
  location_id = "us-central"
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error creating App Engine application: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden
```

I have already given the service account running the Terraform the `Owner` role on the project.

I'm not sure what else I can try. Everything I've found has been related to giving this role to the account performing the action.

Comment: Try this way https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#create_service_account

Comment: How are you assigning the service account with Owner role to Terraform? A common problem is you are not using the identity that you think you are.

Comment: Or maybe he doesnt have access to the correct project ID please do a test with example here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/app_engine_application

Comment: The credentials are being passed in via GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. I'm going to try having a look to see if I can somehow verify that the account is the one I think it is. This terraform is part of another module and all the other resources are working correctly except that one.

Comment: Part of my constraints for this is I can't modify the Terraform. This Terraform has run on other environments and worked in the past. I'm trying to run this on a new environment and the person who set it up is no longer working on it. I'm trying to see what permissions I could be missing or what could be misconfigured so that it would cause this to fail.

Comment: Have you also verify the authentication by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#verifying_authentication)?

Comment: @RobertG I've verified the authentication because the rest of the Terraform works. I also added a line to the CI job's step that outputs the service account being used and indeed it's the correct account. All other resources in Terraform get created except this one.

Comment: @JohnHanley I verified the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable is pointing to the right service account.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that the service account is created in a different project than the one I'm trying to create the app engine app in, even though it has the Owner role in the target project.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this was happening to me was becasue i misunderstood how the provider configuration worked.

In our provider, the `access_token` field is being set. I thought the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable overrode anything set on the provider in the Terraform code, but it turns out that's not true for the `access_token`. The `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` was actually doing nothing.